# Convert minutes to hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: c#, timer

Im my interface I'm letting the user input X amount of minutes that they can pause an action for.

How can i convert that into hours, minutes and seconds?

I need it to update the countdown labels to show the user the time left.

Comment: I am only able to convert it to one format, but i need to calculate hours, mins and secs

Comment: What is the format of the user entry?

Comment: The format is in minutes

Comment: TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(TotalTime));
                    string label = Convert.ToInt32(span.TotalHours).ToString()+":"+span.Minutes;
                    return label;

Answer (score 57):

First create TimeSpan and then format it to whatever format you want:

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
string label = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Answer (score 12):

Create a new `TimeSpan`:

```
var pauseDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
```

You now have the convenient properties `Hours`, `Minutes`, and `Seconds`. I should think that they are self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that should give you someplace to start. The Timer is set for 1000ms. It is using the same ideas as the other answers but fleshed out a bit more.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TimeSpan duration;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      duration  =  duration.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); //Subtract a second and reassign
      if (duration.Seconds < 0)
      {
          timer1.Stop();
          return;
      }

      lblHours.Text = duration.Hours.ToString();
      lblMinutes.Text = duration.Minutes.ToString();
      lblSeconds.Text = duration.Seconds.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)))
        {
            int minutes;
            bool result = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out minutes);
            if (result)
            {
                duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
                timer1.Start();
            }
        }

    }
}
```