# How can I convert HH:MM:SS type to Second?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wmp

How can I convert HH:MM:SS Format to Second?

For example I want to turn `01:20:30` into 1 Hr = 3600 Sec + 1200 Sec + 30 Sec =  `4830 Sec`.

Then I can jump to a specific second on WMP. I want to take mp3 path from MsSQL as you can see.  When the form is closed i want to Update the current time from the Database.

Example:

I'm listening to music at this moment, and I'm `03:52` into the track.  Then I close the form and re-open music.  I want to continue the track at the same time I closed the form (`03:52`). How can i do that with Ms SQL ?

My current code:

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select dosyayol from ses", con);
        SqlDataReader oku = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (oku.Read())
        {

          pth = oku["dosyayol"].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
        Player.URL = pth;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459879/convert-minutes-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse(pth);
ts.TotalSeconds();
```